# Eclipse file search regular expression operation

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace, full-text-search, notepad++

I have strings like `catApple`, `catBoy`, `catChild`, ... `catRobIsAGoodBoy`, ... `catZebraIsAnAnimal` as class names in my application.

Now I have to remove the `cat` prefix from all class names. Using File Search in Eclipse I can search for `cat[A-Z]` and that gives me all my matched class names (also ensuring that strings like `cat)` are filtered out). Additionally I have to lowercase the new first character.

Can I use a `$` operator in my replace command in some way and achieve this?

E.g. `cat[A-Z]` gives me `catMercedesIsACar` and I convert it to `mercedesIsACar`.

[image: Eclipse File Search]

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot do that in Eclipse, but you can do that in Notepad++.

Comment: That sounds inconvenient. Because I need to do this across several files. Nevertheless, how can I do it in NPP?

Comment: I think the safest will be `\bcat([A-Z])` -> `\l$1` (with the word boundary `\b` since `cat` is at the beginning of the word, right?). Actually, there is an option *Replace in Files* in NPP.

Comment: Yes `cat` is at the beginning of every string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Eclipse regex S&R feature does not support `\l` / `\L...\E` operators that can be used in the replacement pattern to perform additional lower-casing operation, you can actually use Notepad++ to search and replace in many files.

In *Replace in Files* in NPP (press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>), use

```
\bcat([A-Z])
```

and replace with `\l$1`. The word boundary `\b` will match `cat` only at the beginning of the words.  **Note** that *Match case* is ON.

[image]

Comment: The `$1` backreference only gets the value captured with the pattern inside the first pair of unescaped parentheses (that is, `[A-Z]`), and turns this value lowercase with `\l`. This only works with ASCII letters, but I guess you need just that.

Comment: Ah.. Well this solution worked pretty neat. Thanks Wiktor. :)

Comment: Tip: I also learnt that `\u' can be used to convert a lowercase match to uppercase.

Comment: Yes, and `\U...\E` to only upper a specific portion of the replacement pattern.

Comment: Can you recommend a website where I can find more of these functions like `\l` and `\u`? Thanks a lot.

Comment: There a [whole *Replacement Text Case Conversion* Web page devoted to them at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html).